# How to specify flexible array member size in struct during static declaration

Tags: c

Consider the following definition where we specify a struct with a flexible array member for its last attribute.

```
typedef struct cache_s
{
    int length;

    char data[];
} cache_t;
```

Normally, we can configure the size of `data` during runtime dynamically like so, where `n` is the size of `data`

```
cache_t* my_dynamic_cache = malloc(sizeof(cache_t) + sizeof(char)*n);
```

However, how would we go about specifying the same thing when we have static allocation of the variable instead?

```
cache_t my_static_cache;
```

Comment: well, you cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want variable `cache_t s;` to be allocated on the stack then you cannot have flexible size array member `char data[];` since there is no way to allocate memory for it.

**It is not possible to modify the array base address, array base address is a constant pointer.**

```
 my_static_cache.data = malloc(100); // it would fail for char data[]
```

You would have to use a 'classical' approach with `char *data;` which you  surely know already:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct cache_s
{
    int length;  
    char *data;
} cache_t;

int main(void)
{
    cache_t my_static_cache;
    char  *str  = "123456789";

    my_static_cache.data = malloc(100);
    strcpy(my_static_cache.data,str);

    printf("%s",my_static_cache.data);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
123456789
```

Comment: do you know what a flexible array member is?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you for your question. I hope I do, but I am not sure how can I  properly allocate memory for `char data[];` in the above situation. That is why, I have proposed an alternative approach.

Comment: OP wants a static allocation and sure knows how to dynamically allocate. It's just not possible to do so.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you for your confirmation. I have updated the answer accordingly.